# Milter greylist libmilter not found

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, sendmail

I am trying to install milter-greylist.
  http://hcpnet.free.fr/milter-greylist/
 After downloading and unarchiving, I am trying to run the configure script and I get this error:

```
Required libmilter not found. Use --with-libmilter
```

I also tried running it with

```
./configure --with-libmilter=/usr/lib/libmilter
```

The result is the same.

I do have libmilter installed

```
/usr/lib/libmilter/libsm.a
/usr/lib/libmilter/libsmutil.a
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libmilter-dev
/usr/share/doc/libmilter-dev/copyright
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libmilter-dev
/usr/share/bug
/usr/lib/libmilter/libmilter.so.1.0.1
/usr/lib/libmilter/libmilter.so
/usr/share/doc/libmilter-dev/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmilter-dev/NEWS.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libmilter-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/bug/libmilter-dev
```

Os is:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Any ideeas what I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

My guess: You need a sendmail with libmilter enabled.

In sendmail source

In `devtools/Site/site.config.m4`

You need:

> APPENDDEF(`conf_libmilter_ENVDEF', `-DMILTER')

and

> APPENDDEF(`conf_libmilter_ENVDEF', `-D_FFR_MILTER_ROOT_UNSAFE ')